# C# WPF D3 (Dynamic Data Display) Charting Project

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, dynamic-data-display

**I'm trying to use D3. First i was downloaded last release and open it via VS2012. Without do any change i try to run test project and i receive strange error message at runtime, details are below. Hoe can i solve this problem?**

```
System.Security.VerificationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233075
  Message=Operation could destabilize the runtime.
  Source=DynamicDataDisplay
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts.AxisControl`1..ctor()
       at Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts.NumericAxisControl..ctor() in c:\Projects\DynamicDataDisplay\Charts\Axes\Numeric\NumericAxisControl.cs:line 10
       at Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts.NumericAxis..ctor() in c:\Projects\DynamicDataDisplay\Charts\Axes\Numeric\NumericAxis.cs:line 18
       at Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts.HorizontalAxis..ctor() in c:\Projects\DynamicDataDisplay\Charts\Axes\Numeric\HorizontalAxis.cs:line 18
       at Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter..ctor() in c:\Projects\DynamicDataDisplay\ChartPlotter.cs:line 16
       at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.InvokeDelegate(Action`1 action, Object argument)
       at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.CallCtorDelegate(XamlTypeInvoker type)
       at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.CreateInstance(XamlTypeInvoker type)
       at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(Object[] arguments)
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Own question and own solution:) I solved my problem. Problem is inconsistency of library and test project build target platform. When i change test project build target platform from x86 to any cpu, problem solved. Still i don't understand VS2012 error message meaning:) But anyway problem is solved.